# Printing an array of String sent from Spring MVC Controller shows only "toJSON" in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a list of String (department names) passed from a controller to a JSP page.  I need to get each individual name and use it as the key to a map (the map value will be a list of employees for that department).  However, when I do alert for each department name, I got a string "toJSON".  How do I get each name in a readable string?  Some department name contain special character like apostrophes, slash.  Many Thanks!

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDepartment", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
 public ModelAndView getDepartment()
 {
     ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
     mv.addObject("depNameList", depNameList); // depNameList is a type of List<String> 
     mv.setViewName("displayDepartment");
     return mv;
  }
```

JSP:

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
    var depArr = "${depNameList}";    
    alert(depArr); // this printed a list of department names
    for ( var i in depArr)
    { 
         alert("i=" + i); // this printed "i=toJSON"
         alert("i=" + JSON.stringfy(i)); // this didn't get invoked.
    }
  });
```

Here is how I solved the issue with Remdo's suggestion (Thank you!).  I didn't change on the controller side.

```
  var depArr =[]
 <c:forEach items="${depNameList}" var="depName">
      depArr.push("${depName}");
  </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer here. Its pretty much same scenario. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29151812/display-arraylist-send-from-spring-controller-to-jsp/29158449#29158449

Answer (score 1):

> alert("i=" + JSON.stringfy(i)); // this didn't get invoked.

because `i` is not a JSON object, `depArr` has a string not array of string,

```
 mv.addObject("depNameList", depNameList); // depNameList is a type of List<String>
```

if you print `depNameList` in console, output would be like:

[a, b, c, d] //this is invalid JSON, missing qoutes(`"` OR `'`)

Also, If you run with above statement compiler will throw a error like:

```
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']'
```

**Solution**:

Change:

```
var depArr = "${depNameList}";
```

To:

```
var depArr =[]
<c:forEach items="${depNameList}" var="depName">
     depArr.push(\"${depName}\");
</c:forEach>
```

**See Also:**

- [Java EE 5 tutorial - JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html)

Comment: it has one problem with your approach, I added alert("depArr: " + depArr.toString()) after the for loop and it didn't get invoked.  I looked from "View Source", it shows for each department, depArr.push(' Andy O'Neil'), where O' is in different color from "Andy".  I think this special character causes some issue.  How do i resolve it ?

Comment: @jlp put under quotes. Answer updated.. and invoke `toString()` on your controller. Update your question to show us what you have done.

Comment: problem solved with your approach.  Thank you so much